# Centralizar imagem no meio da tela Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Como faço para alinhar uma imagem no centro da tela no Android? Estou usando o código abaixo, mas ele fica centralizado no topo da tela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.projeto.acessosistema.SplashActitivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logomarca"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Consegui, troquei  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" por  android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: Isso mesmo! Por favor, marque a resposta como correta!

Comment: Desculpe Túlio pela demora. Marquei como resposta correta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque o valor do atributo **android:layout_gravity** por:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

ou apenas:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```